# Javascript switches not giving expected outcome

Tags: javascript

Why does the below return with saying "You've won a smartwatch and tickets to the circus"?

I was under the impression that winner would have to equal 3 so that it would select case 3 which contains "a smartwatch and " and then it would automatically go down the list to default and add that to the end, making it say "You've won a smartwatch and tickets to the circus" but that does not seem the be the case.

How does setting prize to `""` make this print out as it does?

This is part of a Udacity lesson, I do not understand how this code works and the website doesn't explain very well.

```html
var prize = "";

switch (winner) {
  case 1:
    prize += "a trip for two to the Bahamas and ";
  case 2:
    prize += "a four piece furniture set.";
    break;
  case 3:
    prize += "a smartwatch and ";
  default:
    prize += "tickets to the circus.";
}

console.log("You've won " + prize);
```

Comment: Please include the part where `winner` is assigned.

Comment: I don't get it. You ask why it's doing that, then explain precisely why it's doing that and then say it's not doing that when it is.

Comment: The code never defines winner as being 3, if it did then I would understand how this code works as it does.

Comment: I'm wondering if my lack of understanding what += does in the code is contributing to my lack of understanding of what is going on here. I appreciate all the time and energy all of you are contributing to helping me understand this.

Answer (score 0):

If winner hits case 3, it will append the smartwatch string. Then, there's no `break` after that statement so it'll fall through to the default case as well.

Answer (score 0):

In switch statements, when you use `case` , it will run the commands depends on your variable (winner in this code)

If you don't use `break` in a case, it will go until it reach the `break` keyword or the `default` case.

So if your `winner == 1` then your `prize` would be  **"a trip for two to the Bahamas and a four piece furniture set.";** and it reach the `break` keyword, so it exit the switch statement!

And so if your `winner ==3` your `prize` would be **"a smartwatch and tickets to the circus."**

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to understand what you are asking for and I cant get it completely.
I would introduce the logic of getting

> "You've won a smartwatch and tickets to the circus"

to you.

First the prize is initialized with empty string "".

```
prize = "";
```

When the winner is equal to 3, the prize would be "a smartwatch and ".

```
prize = "a smartwatch and ".
//becoz prize += "a smartwatch and ";
```

Then as there is no break after this line. Therefore, the program will continue to the default case and add "tickets to the circus." to prize

```
prize = "a smartwatch and tickets to the circus.";
//becoz prize += "tickets to the circus.";
```

Therefore the final output is "You've won " + prize;

```
result = "You've won " + prize;
// equal to
result = "You've won " + "a smartwatch and tickets to the circus.";
```